# How to compare two dataframes and find matches from columns (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

let's say we have the following code example where we create two basic dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Creating Dataframes
a = [{'Name': 'abc', 'Age': 8, 'Grade': 3},
     {'Name': 'xyz', 'Age': 9, 'Grade': 3}]
 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
b = [{'ID': 1,'Name': 'abc', 'Age': 8},
     {'ID': 2,'Name': 'xyz', 'Age': 9}]
 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
 
# Printing Dataframes
display(df1)
display(df2)
```

We get the following datasets:

```
    Name   Age  Grade
0   abc    8    3
1   xyz    9    3


    ID   Name   Age
0   1    abc    8
1   2    xyz    9
```

How can I find the list of columns that are not repeated in these frames when they are intersected? That is, as a result, I want to get the names of the following columns: `['Grade', 'ID']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`symmetric_difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.symmetric_difference.html)

```
res = df2.columns.symmetric_difference(df1.columns)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Index(['Grade', 'ID'], dtype='object')
```

Or as an alternative, use [`set.symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference)

```
res = set(df2.columns).symmetric_difference(df1.columns)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'Grade', 'ID'}
```

A third alternative, suggested by @SashSinha, is to use the shortcut:

```
res = df2.columns ^ df1.columns
```

but as of pandas 1.4.3 this issue a warning:

> FutureWarning: Index.**xor** operating as a set operation is
> deprecated, in the future this will be a logical operation matching
> Series.**xor**.  Use index.symmetric_difference(other) instead.   res
> = df2.columns ^ df1.columns

Comment: I didn't know about the warning my bad. In normal python, the shortcut helps a lot when you are limited to a line length of 80 characters...